# Passenger rake not found! Ubuntu (10.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rake, passenger

Okay, so I installed rvm and everything as root. 
Then I installed Ruby Enterprise Edition with rvm.

Now I've been having a TON of issues with rake and rvm so far and I'm not too sure as to why.

I had to manually create links in my /usr/local/bin to rake to get rake working.

But when I passenger-install-nginx-module

```
Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Nginx module installer, v2.2.15.

This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
shouldn't take more than 5 minutes in total.

Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

 1. This installer will compile and install Nginx with Passenger support.
 2. You'll learn how to configure Passenger in Nginx.
 3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
solve any problems.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.


--------------------------------------------

Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... not found
 * rack... found
 * OpenSSL development headers... found
 * Zlib development headers... found

Some required software is not installed.
But don't worry, this installer will tell you how to install them.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.
```

But rake is in my path

```
root@li84-12:/usr/bin# rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2377:in `raw_load_rakefile'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Ideas anyone? This is getting in the way of my clients project =\

Comment: serverfault.com will get you more answers for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Passenger 3. It has much improved RVM support.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing and the following comment on the googlecode thread was insightful.

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=227#c8

Short version - it looks for rake in the same directory that your ruby binary is installed (and not in your $PATH). The quick and dirty fix was to drop a symlink in place for rake into the ruby bin directory.

Eg.

Ruby Binary = `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Rake Binary = `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/rake`

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/rake /usr/local/bin/
```

That seemed to do the trick in my case.